# Adding to List Prints true in Velocity

Tags: apache, velocity, vtl

I am trying to add some string values to a list in Velocity. When I run the code it works alright. But the line where it adds the value prints true. Is it always like that in Velocity? I am new to Velocity templates, so cant figure it out myself.

```
#set ($uniqueInterfaces     =   [])
#if($ipv4interfaceName == $ipv6interfaceName)
    $uniqueInterfaces.add($ipv4interfaceName)
#end
```

Its part of larger code with a nested foreach. It has two matches in it, so the output is:

```
true
true
```

I do not need this true being printed at all!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Java's [`List#add`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add(E)) method returns boolean, that's why this return value is printed in your html output.

You can hide it simply by assigning the output of the add method to a dummy variable:

```
#set ($uniqueInterfaces     =   [])
#if($ipv4interfaceName == $ipv6interfaceName)
    #set ($swallow = $uniqueInterfaces.add($ipv4interfaceName))
#end
```