# using put on a map in velocity prints the instruction

Tags: velocity

I have a map in a velocity template that is dynamically modified. A simplified example to illustrate the point is below.

```
#set($testMap = {})

## this stuff isn't static so I can't just create 
## the map as key-value pairs in the declaration

$testMap.put("a", "A")
$testMap.put("b", "B")

$testMap
```

The above generates

> > $testMap.put("a", "A") $testMap.put("b", "B") {a=A, b=B}

I don't want the "put" instructions to show in the template.

Comment: Are you looking for this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16398116/velocity-template-engine-key-value-map?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you initialize your map with entries:

```
#set (testMap = {"a" :  "A" , "b" : "B"})
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your input. I would have liked to do that but the map's contents aren't known when it's initialized; the `put` instructions are done later dynamically inside of a loop and a few conditions.

Answer (score 0):

To stop it from printing the instruction, I used dummy assignment variables

```
#set($testMap = {})

## this stuff isn't static so I can't just create 
## the map as key-value pairs in the declaration

#set($tmp = $testMap.put("a", "A"))
#set($tmp = $testMap.put("b", "B"))

$testMap
```

This prints

> > {a=A, b=B}

A similar question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40032484/adding-to-list-prints-true-in-velocity).

I don't think it's a duplicate; `Map.put(K, V)` returns the `V` which isn't the same as the string literal `$testMap.put("a", "A")`.